# If statement returning the wrong value?

Tags: python, string, if-statement

An `if` statement in Python evaluates and it appears returns the non-expected value.

```
p = sub.Popen('md5.exe -n md5.exe',stdout=sub.PIPE,stderr=sub.PIPE)
md5, errors = p.communicate()
print md5
abc = "8D443F2E93A3F0B67F442E4F1D5A4D6D"
print abc
if md5 == abc: print 'TRUE'
else: print 'FALSE'
```

`repr(md5)` is `'8D443F2E93A3F0B67F442E4F1D5A4D6D\r\n'`.

The 2 strings are the same, but yet it evaluates and prints `FALSE`.

What's happening here, and how can this be solved?

Comment: Please `print repr(md5)` and `print repr(abc)`, then **update** the question with the output from each print.

Comment: Try printing `repr(md5)` on line 3. Are you sure they're the same?

Comment: Can you do: I suppose there's a line break somewhere or something along that lines. try: `md5.strip() == abc`instead. Otherwise, run `print repr(md5)` and post back

Comment: @S.Lott thx. repr(md5) is '8D443F2E93A3F0B67F442E4F1D5A4D6D\r\n'
thx!

Comment: Please **update** the question with the output from each print statement.  Please include both outputs.  Please **update** the question.  "The 2 strings are the same" claim is false.

Comment: If your goal is not to learn how the subprocess module works, you might want to check out [hashlib](http://docs.python.org/library/hashlib.html).

Comment: @krtek, Don't forget to mark answers as acceepted if it solved your problem. There's an icon for that to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `md5` contains trailing whitespace, which the `abc` value does not have. Most command-line programs end with a line break because it can be disruptive to shell users not to. It's possible to output this to the [standard error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stderr#Standard_error_.28stderr.29) stream so as not to interfere with programs like yours, but this is often not done.

You can use the string method [`.strip()`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) to remove all whitespace from the beginning and end of a string. For example,

```
md5 = md5.strip()
```

---

If you were using Python 3, the same error could have be caused because the `Subprocess` object's `.communicate()` method returns `bytes` objects, which are not be equal to any strings.

Comment: They're not spaces. It's a windows linebreak.

Comment: @phant0m: The windows linebreak is two characters, commonly summarized as "whitespace".

Comment: @S.Lott I originally use just said "spaces". I edited the post in response to his comment.

Comment: @Jeremy Banks: @phant0m's comment is still almost wrong, no matter what the question said or didn't say.

Comment: @S.Lott: I know it's two characters... which is why there are two escape sequences... You have a point though, the wording could have been better.